# Probability that at least $m$ molecules are in a given box

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Imagine we have $N$ molecules that are distributed randomly into $K$ boxes. What is the probability that a given box contains at least $m$ molecules? (For example, we could have $N=10K$, $m=20$ and we can think of $K$ as large.)

I'm not sure how to approach this problem... I'm thinking that we can model this as a multinomial distribution. We know that on average each box should contain $\frac{N}{K}$ molecules, but I don't know if it helps at all. From the example, I also think that we can consider a limiting behaviour since we know $K$ is large.

Comment: I guess, it is also assumed that each molecule has equal probability to be in each box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each of the $N$ molecules is equally likely to end up in any box, and this is independent for each of them, the distribution of the number $X$ of molecules in each box is [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with parameters $(N,p)$ where $p=1/K$. Hence the probability that a given box contains at least $m$ molecules is
$$
P(X\ge m)=\sum_{i=m}^N {N\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{N-i}.
$$
Note that if $N,K\to\infty$ such that $N/K\to\lambda>0$, then the limit is a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda$.

For the Poisson approximation, you will get
$$
P(X\ge m)\approx\sum_{i=m}^\infty \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}
=1-\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}
$$
which is $0.00345...$ in your example.